# Error while Installing Cython for Python

Tags: python, windows, dll, cython

So I've been trying to install Cython on my Windows 7 machine. I try installing it using command prompt.
I've successfully installed installed MinGW compiler.
Successfully installed Visual C++ compiler for Python 2.7
Now when I try installing Cython using following command in **CMD** :

```
python setup.py install
```

I get following error : **cc1.exe - System error**. and zlib1.dll missing error message in pop-up.

So as alternative install I tried installing by downloading Wheel from unofficial binaries for python and doing

`pip install file.whl`

and setup ran successfully, but when I try to build any file (Cythonize it so it can be converted into .c code for compilation) I face same error again.

I tried downloading zlib1.dll manually and placed it in System32 directory too but same issue persists.

Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this issue? Is it my system problem or some installation? If further information on error is required kindly post in comments so that I can edit question with further requirements.

Comment: To build and use Cython, all you need is the [Visual C++ compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). I'd remove MinGW, which apparently wasn't installed properly.

Comment: Zlib is part of the Python standard library https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html. If you just go to Python and type `import zlib` does that work? If not, it's probably a problem with how you've installed Python.

Comment: @DavidW, that has nothing to do with the MinGW installation [missing zlib1.dll](http://superuser.com/questions/789397/mingw-gcc-missing-zlib1-dll). FYI, python27.dll has the zlib library linked statically (built from source maintained in the CPython repository) as part of the built-in zlib extension module (see `sys.builtin_module_names`).

Comment: As to manually adding zlib1.dll, it could be that cc1.exe is a 32-bit executable that needs a 32-bit version of the DLL, which would need to go in SysWOW64 instead of System32. Preferably it should go in the application directory instead of a system directory.

Comment: @eryksun you're quite right. I didn't read it carefully enough.